# HorrizontalScrollView Full Width

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

Well, I've developed a `HorizontalScrollView` with some buttons inside.

I'm able to get the width of this `HorizontalScrollView` through `getWidth()`. But that returns the width of the displayed `HorizontalScrollView`, not the full extension.

How could I get the full width? I mean, the full width including the buttons that are not displayed on the screen?

Cheers.

Comment: Are you referring to the width of the entire content of your View? Post the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `HorizontalScrollView` should have only 1 child (a horizontal `LinearLayout` or something).  Try getting the width of that view.